# PDF some objects become blacked out after downloading from gmail

Tags: pdf, pdf-viewer

I'm downloading a pdf file that someone sent me from gmail, and in the preview everything looks perfect. However, when I download it and open it, some objects become 'blacked out'. I don't think this has anything to do with sensitive/redacted content.

[image]

here is the url for the pdf:
[NAPCO_K3DGTL_USER_GUIDE](http://centuryalarms.com/manuals/NAPCO_K3DGTL_USER_GUIDE.pdf)

Interestingly enough, on some computers it shows up properly.

Comment: I'm afraid you simply see the effects a PDF which is not completely trivial, can show on PDF viewers which only support the basics of the PDF specification.

Comment: ***+1*** for pimping the OP with some supporting illustrations. Will answer later -- have no time right now.

Comment: On first sight there is nothing unusual with this PDF. My initial suspicion was that there might be some transparency involved, which Chrome's PDF and Apple's Preview.app PDF renderers would not be able to display properly. However: there is no transparency on the first page. My next suspicion, that some specific image compression parameter may confuse these renderes is also void: there is no image on the first page other than the small logo in the lower right corner, there are only vector drawings and texts strings. More detailed analysis has to follow later...

Comment: @KurtPfeifle This is so bizarre I'm pulling my hair out on this one. It looks just fine on both my PC laptops, but not my mac. I think this has to do with that somehow.